# Rigorous Proof of Infinite Number of Equivalence Classes

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let X $=\mathbb{R}$

Let $x \sim y \leftrightarrow x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It is intuitively obvious why this would have an inifinite number of equivalence classes. Is there a rigorous way of proving this?

Comment: It's not hard to exhibit an infinite list of non-equivalent members.

Answer (score 4):

Say $x,y\in [0,1)$ with $x\neq y$. Can $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In that case $0 < |x -  y| < 1$, so $x - y$ is not an integer.

Comment: That's assuming $y<x$, in general you may have $-1<x-y<1$. But that's not the point. The conclusion here is that every number $x\in [0,1)$ gives rise to a different equivalence class.